# How to check additional field Laravel 9 + breeze

Tags: laravel, laravel-breeze

I added new field **'approved'** to **USERS** table. Field is index for now it could be 0 or 1. On user login I want to check this field and if it's 0 do not User let login. How to do in Laravel 9 breeze?

Comment: Hi, create a middleware to check this, if not approved, force logout.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a closure in the `attempt()` method in `authenticate()` method at `app\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest.php`

In LoginRequest

```
    public function authenticate()
    {
        $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

        if (! Auth::attempt(array_merge($this->validated(),[
                fn($query) => $query->where('approved', 1) // check if the user is approved if not it will not authenticate the user
            ]), $this->boolean('remember')))
            {
            RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => trans('auth.failed'),
            ]);
        }

        RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go to **LoginRequest** and write something like this in **authenticate()** method

```
$user = User::where('email', $this->email)->first();

if(!$user->approved) {
        throw message here and redirect 
}
```